# Algorithm to assign task to resources

Tags: algorithm, resources, task

Given are tasks (jobs) and resources (people). Each task has a duration and a location. Each person has some time available for work and a starting location. This is continuous,  a person can be available from 8-15 without any breaks in between. Create an algorithm for such assignment of tasks to resources that as many jobs as possible are assigned and total travel time is as short as possible. Travel times between all locations are known. There is no limit of jobs and resources.

Which algorithm can I use???

Thx.

The solution I've found is the following:

1 - . Catch a task with a duration and locallización .

. 2 - Assign the task to a person in the same location.

. 3 - Browse all tasks and go assigning tasks to people who are not assigned any task that match the
locations .

. 4 - If a person has no assigned task because there are no jobs that match their location are
asiganará him a task that is in a location where the travel time is minimal.

. 5 - Once all people have an assigned task , it is gathering tasks and assigning people will go ,
considering that the travel time is minimized.

. 6 - Keep in mind that the more homework time travel time should not exceed 7 hours, since the
Hours are from 8 to 15 for all. You always have to consider this evidence when a task is assigned
a person .

. 7 - If the task Z is to assign a person And because the travel time is minimal or because it is the only one who
He has time available and that Z exceeds task work time available, search through other people some
where the task assigned to (X ), plus the travel time from the last task that is assigned to the person and
the location of the task X fit in the hours you have available and the Z fit person task in X.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this problem is definetly [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard), at least for the general case.

Note that even if you have 1 person, and your jobs are at various locations, and your person need to do all of them - this is the [Traveling Salesman Problem (TSP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).

The formal reduction is:

Given an instance of TSP, create an instance of your problem with one resource (person), all takes take 0 (or very close to it) time, and distances between locations remains the same. A solution to this problem is the solution to the original TSP problem and vise versa.

Thus, the problem is NP-Hard, and **there is no known polynomial solution to it**, and most believe one does not exist.

Some possible solutions are heuristics such as [Hill Climbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing) and [Genetic Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm), or if you need an exact solution - you are going to need [brute forc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search)e here - check all possibilities.

Sorry for the bad news, but at least you won't be looking for something that does not exist (or is unkown to anyone yet at least)

Comment: You should have mentioned held-karp dp solution to TSP which O(2^n*n^2) better than brute force .http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Comment: @VikramBhat I am not sure that this problem can be reduced so easily to TSP (The other way around is easy as I've shown..)

Comment: I added the solution to the initial question

Comment: and if the persons time does not have to be continuous,  a person can be available from 8-10 and 12-15. What would the solution be?